# Having error while creating maven project Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, plugins

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.3.0

Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.3.0

while creating maven project getting error that plugin error. after project creating it gives plugin error in pom.xml file in first row.

**